# Not getting the space and lines in my text modal

Tags: css, reactjs

I think because I am using p tag.

```
           <DialogContent>
              <Grid
                style={{ marginTop: "8px" }}
                container
                spacing={0}
              ></Grid>
              <p>
                {this.state.eulaEncText ? this.state.eulaEncText : null}
              </p>
            </DialogContent>
```

[image]

here I am not able to see the lines and tabs as in the original text.

Comment: they are not in the modal or they are incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using css using the `white-space` attribute with the value `pre-wrap` on the `p` tag as follow:

```
<DialogContent>
  <Grid
    style={{ marginTop: "8px" }}
    container
    spacing={0}
  ></Grid>
  <p style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>
    {this.state.eulaEncText ? this.state.eulaEncText : null}
  </p>
</DialogContent>
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#values), the value `pre-wrap` does the following:

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at 
> , and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Comment: Okay its worked, How can can i see the exact text formatting. For Ex: I am not able to see bold letters